# Why don't I get data even if I wait for the site to finish loading?

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I have a problem that concerns the functioning of the site from which I want to take the data.
In practice when I download the HTML of the site it downloads everything but not the data I want, I noticed that when you open the site before the data I want comes out there is a buffering gif so I added a delay of many seconds (I also tried several minutes but the result does not change) to allow htmlUnit to load the site but apparently, the problem is not this. I have been looking for answers all afternoon but have found nothing.

I leave you the site: https://www.finderbet.it/surebet/

and the code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*; 
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Scraper {
    private static final String url="https://www.finderbet.it/surebet/";
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebClient client= new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);
        client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

        try {
            HtmlPage page= client.getPage(url);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println(page.asXml());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That "buffer" you are seeing is an `AJAX` call  --  If you were to call it directly .. It gives the data you are looking for. IE https://www.finderbet.it/wp-json/bet/v1/getItems -- You can use `get` parameters to filter the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "buffer" you are seeing is an AJAX call -- If you were to call it directly .. It gives the data you are looking for. IE

```
finderbet.it/wp-json/bet/v1/getItems
```

You can use `get` parameters to filter the JSON including pagination IE

```
https://www.finderbet.it/wp-json/bet/v1/getItems?surebet_do_set_filter=NOPE&action-set-filtri_nonce=d20ddf9c95&bookmakers=&sports=&data_evento_da=&data_evento_a=&profitto_min=&puntate=tutti&orderBy=profitto&order=desc&page=1
```

Which breaks down to:

```
https://www.finderbet.it/wp-json/bet/v1/getItems
    surebet_do_set_filter=NOPE
    action-set-filtri_nonce=d20ddf9c95
    bookmakers=
    sports=
    data_evento_da=
    data_evento_a=
    profitto_min=
    puntate=tutti
    orderBy=profitto
    order=desc
    page=1
```